# How many words with four letters can be formed if each letter could be used maximum $2$ times?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> You have the five letters $A, B, C, D$ and $E$. How many words with four letters can be formed if each letter could be used a maximum of $2$ times? (a letter appears in the word $0, 1$ or $2$ times.)

I have tried $5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot3$ and then thought that the positions can be arranged in $4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$. However, this should be divided by $2$ because $A~A~\_~\_$ and $A~A~\_~\_$ are the same results. But the answer I got was not correct. The correct answer according to the key is $540$.

Answer (score 2):

With $5$ letters, you can make $5^4$ four-letter words.

But among these words,

- there are the ones with one letter which is repeated four times (there are obviously $5$ such words);
- and there are the words with a letter repeated three times. There are $5 \times 4 \times 4$ such words (indeed you have to choose the triple letter - $5$ possibilities, the other letter - $4$ possibilities left, and finally the place of the other letter - $4$ possibilities).

So the total number of words you want to count is
$$5^4 - 5 - 5\times 4 \times 4 = 540$$

Answer (score 1):

There are three cases possible.

#### 1. All letters are distinct

Like ($A, B, C, D$). Selecting $4$ letters out of $5$ and arranging them gives $\displaystyle{5\choose 4}\cdot 4!=120$ ways.

#### 2. Two distinct and two same

(Like $A,B,C,C$). Selecting $3$ letters out of $5$ and again selecting one from those $3$ letters as the fourth letter and arranging them: $\displaystyle{5\choose 3}\cdot{3\choose 1}\cdot\frac{4!}{2!}=360$ ways.

#### 3. Only two distinct letters

(Like $A,A,C,C$). Selecting $2$ letters out of $5$ letters and arranging gives $\displaystyle{5\choose 2}\cdot\frac{4!}{2!\cdot2!}=60$ ways.

Adding all these give us $540$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Why am I getting wrong when I use the logic behind scenario 1 and 2 in scenario 3. (5 1)*(1 1)*(4 1)*(1 1) and then arranging it by 4!/2!*2!

Comment: In order to get 60 I have to arrange it by 4!/2!*2!*2!, which the last 2! does not make sense as the repetition of letters are just 2 in each.

Comment: I am using this method because the sum of all bases becomes 4 and as I am willing to fill 4 positions it makes sense.

Comment: I got it, it should be c(5 2)* c(1 1)* c (1 1) * 4!/2!*2!

Comment: @mustafabadakhsh, would you like to accept the answer? :-)